# Doing simple math in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I need to do some simple math in a Makefile but can't find out how to do it. In a shell script I would do it like this:

```
A=1
B=2
C=$[$A+$B]
```

But how can I do this in a Makefile? Let's use this as a base:

```
A=1
B=2
C=$(A)+$(B)

all:
        @echo 'A is $(A)'
        @echo 'B is $(B)'
        @echo 'C is $(C)'
```

Naturally this outputs `C is 1+2`. How can I rewrite the definition of the variable `C` so the Makefile outputs `C is 3`?

Comment: Can't you just use the shell? Or do you need the calculated value in targets?

Answer (score 1):

use "$(())" in shell

```
all:
        @echo C is $$(($(C)))
```

Edit after one years later:

I did not know you need to used the final value of $C in the Makefile. (You just shown it is only used in the shell script inside the Makefile or I had make mistake) You just need to move my code to the definition of the $C:

```
C=$(shell echo $$(($A+$B)))
```

Comment: No, you just fixed the output. But C is still the string "1+2".

Comment: @kayahr : I did left C unchanged too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the two following methods, both using shell, that work pretty well: **$$(( ... ))** and **`expr ...`**

```
A=1
B=2

#With Double-dollar
SUM_1 = $(shell echo $$(( $(A) + $(B) )))

#With 'expr'
SUM_2 = $(shell expr $(A) + $(B) )

$(info Sum with Double-$$: $(SUM_1))
$(info Sum with 'expr': $(SUM_2))
```

Note that when using `expr`, you **shall** put spaces around the `+` or it will return `1+2`. This is not required when using **`$$`**.

.

When you have `bc` available, you should go with it as it is much clearer code:

```
A=1
B=2
SUM = $(shell echo $(A)+$(B) | bc )
$(info Sum with 'bc': $(SUM))
```

I found the following page very interesting: http://www.humbug.in/2010/makefile-tricks-arithmetic-addition-subtraction-multiplication-division-modulo-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

Like [Lai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179373/lai-jiangshan) said...

```
A=1
B=2
C=$(shell echo $$(( $(A) + $(B) )) )

all:
    @echo 'A is $(A)'
    @echo 'B is $(B)'
    @echo 'C is $(C)'
```